# Shaking Off Players

Tags: fifa-14

When my attacker gets the ball (let's say Real Madrid's Benzema), and there is a defender on him, I can never shake off the defender and I always lose the ball.

When the situation is reversed and I'm the defender against Benzema, the opponent seems to shake my defender off pretty well and continue to score.

I haven't been able to figure out what's the pressure button, or if there is a technique to apply pressure to shake other players off and keep the ball.

I lose many many balls this way, and no need to say, this is hurting my score badly.

Is there any way to shake off other players, and keep the ball? If it helps, I'm playing on the PS4.

Answer (score 1):

Double-flick the R stick forward and a little bit away from the defender. That will sent the ball in front of you, and you can win the race to the ball and get in front of the defender.

Answer (score 0):

From experience if you tap Triangle which makes a through ball.

If there's none of you team in front of you.

The ball will get passed in front of you by about 1/2 a meter and your attacker will break the defenders grasp allowing your attacker to run on the ball without the defender slowing you down and taking the ball.

Note if there is a large difference in stats between players this won't always work.

Comment: Thanks. I'm familiar with the through pass, that work's fine. The problem is more with the lobbed through passes, which cause my attacker to stop the ball with his chest and then I lose control most of the time.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know how to counteract the attacking situation other than to simply change direction of dribbling to "fool" the defender. As for defending, holding "B" on Xbox or circle on PlayStation will cause your defender to pull back/shoulder barge the attacker off the ball, slowing him down greatly. However, be weary as this can result in a free kick if you pull him back for too long.